# Can't update my model

Tags: knockout-2.0

I am new to knockout and realized one of my observable is retains old value even when I update. Below is the knockout code:

```
    ko.observable.fn.store = function () {
    var self = this;
    var oldValue = self();

    var observable = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return self();
        },
        write: function (value) {
            oldValue = self();
            self(value);
        }
    });

    this.revert = function () {
        self(oldValue);
    }
    this.commit = function () {
        oldValue = self();
    }
    return this;
}
ko.extenders.numeric = function (target, precision) {

    var result = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return target().toFixed(precision);
        },
        write: target

    });

    result.raw = target;
    console.log(target);
    return result;
};

 function glass(data) {
    var self = this;
    data = data || {};

    // Data from model
    self.id = data.id;
    self.GlassId = ko.observable(data.GlassId).store();
    self.Description = ko.observable(data.Description).store();
    self.OldCost = ko.observable(data.OldCost).extend({ numeric: 2 });
    self.NewCost = ko.observable(data.NewCost).extend({ numeric: 2 });


    // Local (client) data
    self.editing = ko.observable(false);
};
```

The extender is one that's giving me a problem. When I remove it and use the store fn, I can update my model.
How do I make the extender do what my store fn does as well?

**update**
NewCost observable was using the store function and all was working well. I could update and save my new values in the database. Then I decided to format the numeric value to two decimal places using the extender. After using the extender the new value is not saved or sent to the database. In other ways all other values are sent/saved with the store function.

Comment: It is not clear what is not working, can you be more specific what is retaining its old value? I've created a fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/XG9L8/ so what should we do in it to see your issue?

Comment: @nemesv I have update the the question.

Comment: A `parseFloat` call missing from your numeric extender: `return parseFloat(target()).toFixed(precision);` because the `target()` will be a string and you need to convert it to a number before calling `toFixed` on it... and your `store` implementation looks also strange: you define this new `var observable = ko.computed({` but you don't use `observable` anywhere in the code...